# C++ Issue creating a mouse simulator

Tags: usb, mouse, driver

I have been given the following project to do:

create a program that runs on computer 1. The program will simulate mouse movements and pass that information through a usb cable from computer 1 to computer 2. Computer 2 must believe the information being passed to it is coming from a mouse-device.

Basically computer 2 has to believe that a mouse is connected to its usb-port, when actually it is another computer (computer 1), and computer 1 basically simulates mouse movements. Which movements the computer simulates doesn't really matter because that would probably be the easy bit, the harder bit is actually making the software that makes that possible.

QUESTION: Is there any program that currently does that? If so please tell me which one it is. If there isn't any program you know of, how would I go about making it myself?

PS: I would assume that this project is theoretically possible. I mean the computer 1 would just have to send signals to computer 2 that are similar to the normal signals sent to a computer by an ordinary mouse.

Comment: With what operating system? What did you try? On Linux, read more about [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) since it is doing similar things. See also [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)

Comment: Notice that C++11 does not know about mouses. So your question is obviously operating system specific (OSes are managing physical resources, like mice & keyboards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to act as a USB host as well as a client (keyboard, mouse, etc.) is not typically part of the USB chipset in PCs.  The ability to serve either role requires something unique like [USB OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go); which you can find in some mobile phones.

So no, this is generally not possible with two random PCs and a USB cable.  In any case, you can find a discussion on this here:

[Emulate USB Device with USB Host](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56907/emulate-usb-device-with-usb-host)

The thread mentions that you could make a proxying device with active electronics in it to sit between two host-only devices and be capable of translating to appear as a client to one.  But with just a plain old USB cable you can't.

Since you're so specific about wanting it to be done with USB and no need to install special software you are probably not interested in something like Synergy:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergy_(software)

...but someone else finding this question might be.